# Using UPDATE in Oracle DB OCCI interface

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

I use oracle occi api to update data, code:

```
  Environment * env = Environment::createEnvironment();
    Connection * con = env->createConnection("nm_web","nm_web99","192.168.26.42/orcl");
    Statement *stmt;
    string sqlStmt = 
      "update tb_yctp_daq_record set deal_status=1";
    try{
        stmt = con->createStatement(sqlStmt);
        stmt->execute();
    }catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        cout<<"Exception thrown for updateRow"<<endl;
        cout<<"Error number: "<<  ex.getErrorCode() << endl;
        cout<<ex.getMessage() << endl;
    }
    con->commit();
    con->terminateStatement (stmt);
   
    Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);
    return true;
```

but this code stuck in " stmt = con->createStatement(sqlStmt);"

Comment: What do you mean by 'stuck'? you get an error, or the statement execution takes a long time?

Comment: no error, no message, program run this sentence :"stmt = con->createStatement(sqlStmt), and program do not run, do not quit.

Comment: Hw do you know it is stuck at createStatement and not execute? did you check in the database if your session is doing something? maybe your update is taking too long as it updates all the rows in the table? or some other session is also updating the table and so there are locks ?

Comment: 1.I just cout something around "createStatement()".    2.I use plsql to check database, data is no change. 3. only 6 row in my table. 4 i just found if give the "sqlStmt" to "execute(sqlStmt)"  and change "createStatement()",no parameter to pass,  this program stuck in "execute(sqlStmt)".

Comment: my program is work, but my code not change. I wanna to check database server

Comment: I found by chance that when I use plsql, my program just stuck...

Answer (score 0):

I just not commit update operation in PLSQL tools, this could lead lock this table.